# phpmyadmin: pma__ tables in different databases

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

We have our test webserver and main webserver on the same (virtual) webserver with CentOs7. Having them both there is very convenient for us (small company) for several reasons.

We also have the test database and the main database on that same server, also convenient for several reasons.

We created first the main database via directadmin/phpmyadmin, only much later the test database. We use two different logins for phpmyadmin: one that only accesses the main database. For accessing both test db and main db and also system db's we now use the root login, handy to maintain all databases (test and main and others).

We sometimes sync the two databases (mostly data from main to test to be able to test with up-to-date data, and the structure from test to main after testing code and db). Part of  the structure we want to copy are some phpmyadmin goodies like the popups with foreign keys. phpmyadmin uses a set of pma__xxx tables for this, like `pma__table_info`.

Problem is: we have this set of tables now in both databases, both in the test and main database.

And in these tables, we always find records for both databases. For instance, on the test server, there may be records with `pma__table_info.db_name` set to the main server but also the test server. The same in the main server. Yet the content of the tables is completely different. And I notice that if records are in both `pma__table_info` tables, the system does not necessarily take the `pma__table_info`-info from the server that table is on.

I don't understand (also not after google and looking at https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html):

1. Why is there not a separate database for the set of pma__ tables? Why is it in our database(s)?
2. Why are there two sets pma__ tables, on on each of our databases? Was this just because we made a db copy? But why does phpmyadmin then actually then use records from the copy and not from the original? And why are the tables so different on both db's?
3. So it seems that the pma tables on both databases are used for both databases. How do I know which set of tables is used when? Does that depend on the phpmyadmin login we use?
4. Should we merge the pma__ tables into a separate database and tell phpmyadmin via the config to use this separate database? Would that work if we login with a login that only has access to the main database?

Googling gives no basic answers, only technical stuff but I need to know the basic stuff above first before I figure the technical stuff out.

A link to basic pma__ table info (other than technical config info) is also very welcome.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

So I seem to have find the answers myself in the end. If I am somewhere wrong, please correct.

1. Because phpmyadmin is configured normally to use the current db. So that it goes well when you only have one database. And handy when you don't have access to the config files.
2. See above. phpmyadmin will, afaik, use the first db you open after starting phpmyadmin, and will keep using the tables in this db even after you switch.
3. See 2.
4. Definitely. Create a user and db for pma, adjust the config file with those, and you're good to go.